# cannot retrieve data from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been following some php-mysql tutorial from a textbook. I should be able to retrieve some data from the "books" database, for example if I select author as searchtype and Michael as searchterm I should get some results since the author name is in the database. But, I am not getting any result after I submit the data from form. It just shows following:

```
Search Results 

Number of books found:
```

following is my html code for the form:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Catalog Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Catalog Search</h1>
    <form action="results.php" method="post">
      Choose Search Type:<br />
      <select name="searchtype">
        <option value="author">Author</option>
        <option value="title">Title</option>
        <option value="isbn">ISBN</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      Enter Search Term:<br />
      <input name="searchterm" type="text">
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a database named books and a php script named results.php:

```php
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Search Results</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Search Results</h1>
    <?php
      // create short variable names
      $searchtype=$_POST["searchtype"];
      $searchterm=$_POST["searchterm"];
      if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm)
      {
        echo 'You have not entered search details.
         Please go back and try again.';
        exit;
      }

      $searchterm= trim($searchterm);
      $searchtype = addslashes($searchtype);
      $searchterm = addslashes($searchterm);

      // Create connection
      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","myusername","mypassword","books");

      // Check connection
      if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
      {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

      $query = "select * from books where ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      $num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
      echo '<p>Number of books found: '.$num_results.'</p>';
      for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++)
      {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo '<p><strong>'.($i+1).'. Title: ';
        echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['title']));
        echo '</strong><br />Author: ';
        echo stripslashes($row['author']);
        echo '<br />ISBN: ';
        echo stripslashes($row['isbn']);
        echo '<br />Price: ';
        echo stripslashes($row['price']);
        echo '</p>';
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

What's wrong with the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in addition i found i should use double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection uses `mysqli` extension, therefore your query has to use that as well and not the `mysql_*`

```
$result = mysql_query($query); // Wrong extension. Use mysqli
```

should be

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Then all the subsequent database functions have to use `mysqli_*`, you cannot mix the two together.

Side note:
use **[mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)** instead of `addslashes`.

Comment: thanks it shows Number of books found: 1 but does not show the values of title,author, isbn, price

Comment: Yes because as I mentioned all the subsequent functions have to be `mysqli_*` ones. like `mysql_fetch_array` etc

Comment: Don't use mysqli_real_escape_string use prepared statements, they're much safer

Comment: There is no harm in using `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Your queries become safer or less safer the way you code them, not just by using the term `prepared statements`.

Comment: This is correct.  However, it makes tonnes more sense to use prepared statements than to use escape_string.  It's faster and more reusable.  In this particular case, @anders_reimer leaves himself open by keeping the where clause dynamic without validating the input.  He should confirm that the field input is something that actually exists before building the query from it. It's kind of fun to build a dynamic prepared statement.